# How to enable OPCache for PHP7.1 on MAC Sierra (MAMP)

Tags: php, macos, opcache

I've installed OPCache GUI from [GitHub](https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui) and installed in my Mac. But when I run the page, it shows

> The Zend OPcache extension is installed but not turned on

I've enabled the OPCache in my php.ini file with these

> opcache.enable=1 
>  opcache.enable_cli=1 
> zend_extension=opcache.so
>   opcache.memory_consumption=128
>   opcache.max_accelerated_files=2500
>   opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
>   opcache.revalidate_freq=60
>   opcache.fast_shutdown=1
>   zend_extension=/path/to/opcache.so/file

Please help!

Comment: did you restart your server after enabling it? Are you running plain apache or using MAMP? Can you print your phpinfo();

Comment: Yes. I did restart my server. My Mac is running MAMP. Yes, I can print my phpinfo(), which portion of the phpinfo() do I have to display?

Comment: See if you can find opcache.enable in php info. Also make sure that you modified the right php.ini. MAMP has a bunch of them stored for every version of php ex: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini`

Comment: Oops. opcache.enable is "Off" in phpinfo(). But it's strange, I've installed php 7.1. But in the `/Applicaations/MAMP/bin/php/` folder, I cannot find php 7.1, instead there are 5.3, 5.4, 5.6, 7. I've tried edited the 7. But still doesn't work. Can't find 5.5.3 btw.

Comment: find out which php.ini your server is using in phpinfo if you can.

Comment: I found out which php.ini the server is using. However, I am only able to make changes to `opcache.enable_cli`. not the rest including `opcache.enable`.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your comments. I'll try it out next time.

Answer (score 3):

I found that no matter what you set in `php.ini` the cache is always shown as disabled. The only way that worked, was to activate `OPcache` directly in the MAMP GUI.

Where you find these settings depends on the MAMP variant (standard or pro):

## MAMP PRO

> Language → PHP Settings → Cache module to speed up PHP execution → `OPcache`

[image]

## MAMP

> Settings → General → Cache → `OPcache`

[image]

Comment: how bout non-pro MAMP?

Comment: @AlanYong MAMP > Preferences > General > PHP-Cache > OPCache

Comment: I cannot activate OPcache in the MAMP GUI. It can be selected, but it does not save that selection. It is ALWAYS going back to "off" in the GUI. And PHPAdmin shows it is off. I'm using MAMP 6.4 and php 7.4.16 and trying to edit the file at `MAMP > bin > php > php7.4.16 > conf > php.ini` lines 1738 and thereabouts. What am I missing?

Comment: @Rillieux Found a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74769696/mamp-pro-on-macos-cant-turn-on-opcache/74769697#74769697